# Считывание n байт из файла в память блоком, c++, VS13

Tags: c++, visual-studio, функции

Помогите разобраться:

Написать родовую функцию, которая считывает n байт из файла в память, которая выделяется в родовой функции, считывание блоком. Проверить для данных типа char, int, float, double.

Если напишите функцию с комментариями буду очень благодарен, но хотя бы скажите в каком направлении копать.

Вот что нашел:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main()
{
    FILE * ptrFile = fopen("file.txt", "rb");

    if (ptrFile == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Ошибка файла", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    // определяем размер файла
    fseek(ptrFile, 0, SEEK_END);                          // устанавливаем позицию в конец файла
    long lSize = ftell(ptrFile);                            // получаем размер в байтах
    rewind(ptrFile);                                       // устанавливаем указатель в конец файла
    //здесь задаем количество байтов для считывания
    long n = 5;
    char * buffer;
    if (lSize >= n){
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n); // выделить память для хранения содержимого файла
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            fputs("Ошибка памяти", stderr);
            exit(2);
        }

        size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, ptrFile);       // считываем файл в буфер
        if (result != lSize)
        {
            fputs("Ошибка чтения", stderr);
            exit(3);
        }

        //содержимое файла теперь находится в буфере
        puts(buffer);
    }
    else {
        fputs("Превышено количество байтов для считывания!", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }
    // завершение работы
    fclose(ptrFile);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Как теперь просмотреть что cчитало?

Comment: malloc/new, fread. все собственно, что там писать то

Comment: родовая функция?

Comment: @Mike а что тут более подходит new или malloc?

Comment: @alexolut да именно родовая, а что не так?

Comment: В `c++` нет такого понятия. Вероятно, имелась в виду `шаблонная`?

Comment: @alexolut Гугл говорит что такое понятие есть, не знаю кто и когда его придумал и не страдал ли он родовыми травмами, но похоже термин есть :)

Comment: @Vyacheslav new явно больше подходит, это же ++ и шаблоны

Comment: @Mike если я правило понял гугла, то это понятие относится к управляемому .net коду и обозначает `generic` функции. А судя по тому, что у ТС основные темы из шарпа, то всё становится ясно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, не уверен, что верно понимаю вопрос... Вот это не оно?

```
template<typename T>
T* read(istream&in)
{
    T* t = new T;
    if (!in.read((char*)t,sizeof(T)))
    {
        delete t;
        t = nullptr;
    }
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        ofstream out("test",ios::binary);
        char c   = 'a';
        int  i   = 1234;
        double d = 3.1415926;
        out.write((const char*)&c,sizeof(c));
        out.write((const char*)&i,sizeof(i));
        out.write((const char*)&d,sizeof(d));
    }
    {
        ifstream in("test",ios::binary);
        char * c = read<char>(in);
        int  * i = read<int>(in);
        double*d = read<double>(in);

        cout << *c << endl;
        cout << *i << endl;
        cout << *d << endl;
    }

}
```